# Albums dont show information

Tags: python, django, cmd

I'm watching a tutorial on Django and I've been following along but I've noticed small differences between my Django and his, this all might be because I have the current patch and he has the 2016 version. The problem is that I've been trying to focus on the music app of the project. But whenever I create details of the album such as artist, album_name, genre I then save them in the shell. To then check I reopen the shell and type `Album.objects.all()` and get four unspecified objects.

`<QuerySet [<Album: Album object (1)>, <Album: Album object (2)>, <Album: Album object (3)>, <Album: Album object (4)>]>`

I wrote this line in the models.py file to no avail

```
from django.db import models

# RED pk 1

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist

# RED fk 1
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? If so, your `Album` class doesn't have a `__str__` method, you just have a useless function named `__str__` that's unrelated to the `Album` class. And that's why Python doesn't know how to print out an `Album` object except with that useless generic angle-bracket representation.

Comment: angle-bracket representation?

Answer (score -1):

You have done the `__str__` method wrong. This code might solve your issue.

```
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```